# what is the meaning of gcc/g++ - O2, O3 compiled code

Tags: gcc, g++

I have been programming in C/C++ from couple of years, but I haven't heard about gcc/g++ - O2, O3 compiled code? Can someone help me to understand?

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html

Comment: It's just the level of optimization that GCC employs where o3 is the top  optimization.

Comment: How do I know in which level of optimization is my code running? I am a beginner to this concept.

Comment: @Tanya You generally don't, after compilation, know what optimization level C++ code was compiled with. The only thing that can be baked into the code is debugging symbols, but that is controlled by a different flag entirely.

Answer (score 0):

They are simply options to the compiler that asks it to optimize to varying degrees. The `-O2` option asks for less optimization than `-O3`. Since optimizing can be time-consuming, it's split into these different levels so that you as the developer can choose how to build your code.

During early debugging, optimization is often turned off since it can make single-stepping through code harder, then turned back on for release builds.

Once the code is built, assuming it works, the optimization level it was compiled using no longer matters.